# Google Cloud Functions with Sequelize connecting to PostgreSQL but not to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-functions

I have two Cloud SQL instances:

[image]

This config works (PostgreSQL):

[image]

This config does NOT work (MySQL):

[image]

[image]

Ps.: Connecting to the Public IP from my local machine works..

Sequelize init (for both cases):
[image]

Error log:
[image]

Comment: I use this version of the mysql lib: "mysql2": "1.6.5",

Comment: Whenever possible, you should copy text into the question rather than providing a screenshot.  It will be easier to read and search.